# Rust: how to derive Deserialize for struct with generic types?

Tags: rust, lifetime, serde, serde-json

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct S<'d, T>
  where T: Deserialize<'d>
{
  foo: T,
  other_field: String
}
```

The above code fails to compile, complaining unused lifetime parameter,
but if I remove it, `Deserialize` would missing lifetime.

Can the above code be made correct without using phantom marker or `DeserializeOwned`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code works if you remove the `where` clause completely. The derive will add a `T: Deserialize<'de>` bound automatically for the derived `Deserialize<'de>` implementation.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct S<T> {
  foo: T,
  other_field: String
}
```

For Rust it is common to not restrict generic types at struct/enum declarations. The generic type is only restricted for `impl` blocks where the behavior is needed.